# Running Reactive Native Project giving 404 not found

Tags: react-native

Running react-native sample project gives me a
`404 Not Found. The Server could not locate the resource you request.`

Comment: Did you follow the instructions? I did, and it worked. Where are you seeing that error?

Comment: Found the problem. I was trying this on my system at work which is behind the proxy. Tried this on my laptop, Worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen if you've got an existing service running on port 8081, since that's the port that the packager runs on.

Answer (score 0):

#### OPTION 1

- Load from development server. Start the server from the repository root:
- $ npm start
- To run on device, change `localhost` to the IP address of your computer, and make sure your computer and  iOS device are on the same Wi-Fi network.
  just like this:

> jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.8.190:8081/Examples/2048/Game2048.includeRequire.runModule.bundle"];

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Colin Ramsay's answer, you can check if a service is running on port 8081 by running the following command on OSX:

```
lsof -i :8081
```

If anything is running, something like his will show:

```
COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
nginx    918 Robert    6u  IPv4 0x5c8c06c2a2e769cf      0t0  TCP *:sunproxyadmin (LISTEN)
nginx   1010 Robert    6u  IPv4 0x5c8c06c2a2e769cf      0t0  TCP *:sunproxyadmin (LISTEN)
```

You can then use the **PID** to kill that service:

```
kill -9 918
```